# Concatenation of characters of two strings

Tags: visual-c++

I am working upon this problem.

Write a String class and overload the + operator to mix two strings such that a new string is created with one 
character from each string pieced together until all the characters are mixed. For example 
• "1234567890" + "QWERTYUIOP" = "1Q2W3E4R5T6Y7U8I9O0P"

Can you help me out in concatenating the characters of two strings?

This is the code I have written :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class MY_String : public string
{
  public:
    char *rep;
    MY_String(){}
    MY_String(char *tem)
    {
      rep = new char[strlen(tem)+1] ;
      strcpy(rep,tem); 
    }
    MY_String operator + (const MY_String &rhs)
    {
      char *temp;MY_String obj11("1234567890");
      temp= new char[strlen(rep) + strlen(rhs.rep)+1];//cout<<"TEMP::"<<rhs.rep<<endl;
      temp = strcat(rep,rhs.rep);
      return MY_String(temp);
    }
};
int main()
{
    MY_String obj1("1234567890");
    MY_String obj2("QWERTYUIOP");
    MY_String obj3;

    obj3 = obj1+obj2;
    cout<<obj3.rep;
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know how to overload the `operator+`, the algorithm could be very simple.

```
 string A, B, Result;
 int As = A.size(), Bs = B.size();
 int MixingLenght = min(As,Bs);
 for (int index = 0; index < MixingLength; ++index)
 {
     Result += A[index];
     Result += B[index];
 }
```

Then you would have to decide what to do with the remaining part (if the strings are different in size). You could either ignore it, or append to the end of the `Result`.

Comment: Actually i have overloaded the '+' operator and you have used '+=' operator over here.So is it like one and the same thing?

Comment: No, these are two different things. Also, I am appending `char` in my solution (using `+=`). You could use `std::string::append` instead.

Comment: Oh, you could use recurrence of `+`, of course, but seems like an overkill to me. I am not going to write your homework for you.

Comment: Hey listen I am not asking you to complete my homework and neither i am a school kid.

Comment: I have written the code.The only problem i am facing is as to how to overload the '+' operator.

Comment: @Ankur, what he posted here goes INSIDE your + operator. No need for you to overload += of anything.

Comment: I googled it. The output my program throwing is "1234567890QWERTYUIOP"

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz, I have posted my code.Please suggest me as to how can i solve my problem?

Comment: `temp = strcat(rep,rhs.rep);` that's the line you have to replace. I am done here, you have much more reading to do; your code has many places where it could be improved.

Comment: Yeah I know temp = strcat(rep,rhs.rep); is the line to be replaced. But this is the only problem i dont know as to how to replace it and with what.